# Starting specific program (via wine) in different language

Tags: wine, language-support, winetricks

I have a program that i am trying to run in Hebrew and have not been successful for a long time.

On the file properties under"Command" it says `{env WINEPREFIX="/home/yehoshua/.wine" wine C:\\DBS\\TaklitorTorani.Exe` } and the location is `/home/yehoshua/Desktop`.

I also seem to be geting a second error when trying to run it from the terminal saying

```
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -120, std (d/m/y): 25/10/2015, dlt (d/m/y): 27/03/2015
```

I am at a total loss, and do not know my way around Linux (or and computer language) and am in desperate need of clear detailed guidance. Thank you very very much,